# how to center an image in regards its parent conatiner (android)?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, user-interface

I have to following xml:

```
                    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:id="@+id/layout_refresh"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="110dp"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                          android:visibility="invisible"      
                          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_status_image"    
                          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                          >
                          <!-- 
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" -->
                          <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_refresh"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_refresh_idle"
                          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                          android:paddingRight="6dp"
                          />

                          <TextView android:id="@+id/refresh_text"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:textSize="18sp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/solid_white"                         
                          android:text="Click to refresh"                
                          />
                  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

How can I fix the followings?

1) center the `refresh image` in relate to its parent conatiner.

2) make the text `Click to refresh` fit in the view

Comment: android:centerInParent="true"

Comment: 1. Use : `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` or `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. 2. `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, event hough I'm not sure about the last one, about the height. Have in mind the the `RelativeLayout` has a fixed size, and if the `ImageView` is too big, you might not leave a room for the `TextView`.

Comment: @g00dy why does `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` not sufficient? should I remove it?

Comment: @g00dy and if I want to text to fit and in the remainder, center the image horizontally?

Comment: It's either `layout_centerInParent="true"` or `scaleType="fitXY"` that you need to use, it depends which one suits you best.

Comment: should i remove `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` ?

Answer (score 0):

1)put this attribute in your ImageView

```
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

2) what do you mean by fit in the view? can you post a screen?

Comment: Thanks. I have added a screenshot of the widget

Comment: why does `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` not sufficient? should I remove it?

Comment: I said add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `ImageView` so it will only effect `ImageView`, for `TextView` to be fit in view you should add this line to your textView `android:layout_below="@+id/image_refresh"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` 
.By the way `RelativeLayout` is your parent layout? or else it is also child of another layout?